# Как подключиться к именованному каналу без прав администратора?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-service, ipc

Привет. Есть два приложения на C# - служба (windows service, для службы был указан Account LocalSystem) и клиентское приложение(обычное windows приложение, в данном случае консольное), которые обмениваются информацией по именованным каналам (Named Pipes). Проблема в том, что клиентское приложение может подключиться к службе по именованному каналу только с правами администратора.

Нашёл в сети решение, в котором предлагается назначить серверному именованному каналу PipeSecurity, содержащий один или более PipeAccessRule. После применения этого подхода серверное приложение падает с исключением System.UnauthorizedAccessException. Подскажите, как по именованному каналу осуществить подключение к службе клиентского приложения, которое запущено без прав админа? Делаю так:

Windows Service

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                using (var pipe = new NamedPipeServerStream("test", PipeDirection.InOut, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte))
                {
                    var ps = new PipeSecurity();
                    ps.AddAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name, PipeAccessRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
                    pipe.SetAccessControl(ps);

                    pipe.WaitForConnection();
                    int x = pipe.ReadByte();
                    pipe.WriteByte((byte)(x + 1));
                }
            }
        })
        { IsBackground = true }.Start();
    }
```

Клиент:

```
using (var pipe = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "test", PipeDirection.InOut))
        {
            pipe.Connect();
            pipe.WriteByte(100);
            int x = pipe.ReadByte();
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
```

Пробовал также в коде службы WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name менять на "Everyone", но в этом случае исключение System.Security.Principal.IdentityNotMappedException.

Comment: Попробуйте передать в `PipeAccessRule` вместо первого параметра выражение `new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null)`

Comment: В этом случае также исключение System.UnauthorizedAccessException при попытке назначить PipeSecurity каналу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте такую реализацию:

```
new Thread(() =>
{
    var ps = new PipeSecurity();

    // себе разрешаем все
    ps.AddAccessRule(
        new PipeAccessRule(
            WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Owner,
                PipeAccessRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));

    // остальным только чтение/запись в пайп
    ps.AddAccessRule(
        new PipeAccessRule(
            new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null),
                PipeAccessRights.ReadWrite, AccessControlType.Allow));

    while (true) {
        // параметры безопасности передаем в конструктор, а не в SetAccessControl
        using (var pipe = new NamedPipeServerStream("test", PipeDirection.InOut, 1,
            PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, PipeOptions.None, 0, 0, ps))
        {
            pipe.WaitForConnection();
            int x = pipe.ReadByte();
            pipe.WriteByte((byte)(x + 1));
        }
    }
})
{ IsBackground = true }.Start();
```

Comment: Спасибо! Это действительно работает.